# In MultiSite, can some users automatically have Site Admin rights on all sites, without granting them Network Admin access?

Tags: multisite, users, capabilities

We have some "content specialists" that we'd like to effectively grant Site Admin access to every site on our network automatically, but still don't want them to be able to access the network admin menu. (They shouldn't be able to create new sites, change network settings, etc.)

I'm not sure if there's a good way to filter user permissions for this use case or something else.  I am not looking to actually add them as a Site Admin to every site, just be treated as if they have those capabilities.

Comment: Is it a problem to just grant them Administrator (or Editor enough?) to all the sites? Is it very large or is it growing fast?
It sould be possible to hook the 'user_has_cap' filter to return true for specific user IDs on all sites when not in network admin. A bit dangerous if made wrong.

Comment: It is hundreds of sites, can grow quickly, and we want to be able to easily grant/revoke this access from people.

Comment: Are those users added to all the sub-sites, do they have any role (like subscribers) at those sites at all? If yes, I have a simple solution ready. If not, I have investigate a bit further.

Comment: Nope - they do not exist with a role on any of the subsites.

Comment: It may be possible if all sites use a subdomain or subdir of the main site. If separate domains it's not possible since the user, as set as a cookie, cannot be checked cross domains.

Comment: What could be done is a process that loops through all sites and add the administrator role to the (or multiple) user on each site. To revoke, the opposite must happen. if own domains, they would have to log in to each site, though.

Comment: There are several issues related to actually adding the users to each site, such as receiving emails that go to all Site Administrators when various things happen, and them being totally overwhelmed with "My Sites."  They should be able to act as though they have Site Admin capabilities on each site, without ACTUALLY being a Site Admin on each site.

Comment: A kind og Single Sogn-on might do the trick. Like https://www.miniorange.com/wordpress-single-sign-on-(sso)-for-multisite

Comment: Perhaps a solution that hooks into the `user_has_cap` filter could work